# Ask about how to write php syntax to query mongo obj

Tags: php, mongodb

How can write `php` syntax to find `mongo` object that contain `'910'` in tel field

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("531aabd8a6ddc85421ad9d4d"),
    IDcard: "",
    address: "",
    birthdate: "",
    code: "109901",
    company: "Beger",
    created: "09-07-2014",
    email: "",
    gender: "Male",
    group: "531434e6a6ddc80a565b3deb",
    name: "John Henry",
    note: "",
    photo: "",
    tel: {
        mobile: "0872223910",
        home: "083772771"
    },
    type: "D"
}
```

Comment: Your tel attribute is a sub-document. Are you wanting to inspect the mobile or home number?

Answer (score 3):

In PHP, you can use [**MongoRegex**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongoregex.construct.php)

```
$search = new MongoRegex("/910/");
$cursor = $collection->find(array(
    '$or' => array(
        array("tel.mobile"  => $search),
        array("tel.phone"   => $search)
    )
));

echo "<pre>";
foreach ($cursor as $value) {
    print_r($value);
}
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want a [**`$regex`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) query such as :

```js
db.collection.find({ 
    "$or": [
        { "tel.mobile": { "$regex": "910" } },
        { "tel.home": { "$regex": "910" } },
    ]
})
```

Or directly in PHP syntax:

```php
$collection->find(array(
    '$or' => array(
        array( 'tel.mobile' => array( '$regex' => '910' ) ),
        array( 'tel.home' => array( '$regex' => '910' ) )
    )
));
```

Which is combined with the [**`$or`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) operator to allow a possible match on either field.

Queries with [**`$regex`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) are not very efficient where they are not anchored against the begining of the field, but it is essentially how you find something in the "part of" a string.

Would also strongly recommend a basic code snippet as most examples you will find will be in JSON syntax as appropriate to the MongoDB shell:

```php
print_r( json_decode( $json ) );
```

Comment: OP asked how to write a query in PHP.

Comment: @ChristianP Oh okay then, but the initial complainers and close voters didn't seem to see the answer at all. I really think everyone should be able to read JSON syntax by now and should know how to convert. Clearly someone does if it's all about just posting a PHP code version of exactly the answer that was given a lot earlier. Wouldn't you think.

Comment: @user3721681 It should. Shame that someone thought it was okay to come along and copy the answer. You can help me by accepting the answer I gave before that happened. Glad it helped.